# Dynamic Calculation Using Filter in Datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to dynamically update the sum of dataSet values as I filter and/or paginate a Primefaces dataTable.

The following jQuery example shows **exactly** the behavior I want: http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

See below my main code for this issue:

The jsf

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer">
  <p:row>
    <p:column colspan="6" footerText="Grand Total:" style="text-align:right"/>
      <p:column colspan="7">
        <f:facet name="footer">
          <h:outputText value="#{purchaseOrderController.soma}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###" locale="pl_PL"/>
          </h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
  </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

The method soma:

```
private float soma;

public float getSoma() {
    for (PurchaseOrder p : getItems()) {
        soma += p.getShippingCost().floatValue();
    }
    return soma;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated code**

The bean:

```
@Named(value = "purchaseOrderController")
@ViewScoped
public class PurchaseOrderController extends AbstractController<PurchaseOrder> implements Serializable {

private float soma = 0;
private float somaFiltered = 0;
private List<PurchaseOrder> filteredPurchaseOrder;

public List<PurchaseOrder> getFilteredPurchaseOrder() {
    return filteredPurchaseOrder;
}

public void setFilteredPurchaseOrder(List<PurchaseOrder> filteredPurchaseOrder) {
    this.filteredPurchaseOrder = filteredPurchaseOrder;
}

//return the sum for the FILTERED list - using this method, get a NullPointerException (the filtered list is null)
public float getSomaFiltered() {
    for (PurchaseOrder p : filteredPurchaseOrder) {
            somaFiltered += p.getQuantity() * p.getShippingCost().floatValue();
    }
    return somaFiltered;
}

//return the sum for the ENTIRE list - using this method it's ok
public float getSoma() {
    for (PurchaseOrder p : getItems()) {
        soma += p.getQuantity() * p.getShippingCost().floatValue();
    }
    return soma;
  }

@Inject
private PurchaseOrderFacade ejbFacade;

public PurchaseOrderController() {
    super(PurchaseOrder.class);
}

}
```

The jsf (some columns ommited):

```
<h:form id="PurchaseOrderListForm">
  <p:panel header="#{appBundle.ListPurchaseOrderTitle}">
     <p:dataTable id="datalist" var="item" value="#{purchaseOrderController.items}" 
                  filteredValue="#{purchaseOrderController.filteredPurchaseOrder}"
                  selectionMode="single" selection="#{purchaseOrderController.selected}"
                  rowKey="#{item.orderNum}"
                  paginator="true"
                  rows="10"
                  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
                  >

         <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
         <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
         <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{purchaseOrderController.filteredPurchaseOrder}" update="partialSoma" />

         <p:column sortBy="#{item.quantity}" filterBy="#{item.quantity}">
             <f:facet name="header">
                 <h:outputText value="#{appBundle.ListPurchaseOrderTitle_quantity}"/>
             </f:facet>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.quantity}"/>
         </p:column>
         <p:column sortBy="#{item.shippingCost}" filterBy="#{item.shippingCost}">
             <f:facet name="header">
                 <h:outputText value="#{appBundle.ListPurchaseOrderTitle_shippingCost}"/>
             </f:facet>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.shippingCost}"/>
         </p:column>
         <p:columnGroup type="footer">
             <p:row>
                 <p:column colspan="6" footerText="Grand Total:" style="text-align:right"/>
                    <p:column colspan="7">
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <h:outputText id="partialSoma" value="#{purchaseOrderController.somaFiltered}">
                            </h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for my lateness but I actually not have a lot of time with my work.
I took the time yesterday afternoon to built a little working example. Indeed, I faced some problems for updating a footer with AJAX (cfr : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15658) but it is working with a `<p:remoteCommand />` workaround.

You can find the Eclipse sample project [here](http://sebastien-vanmechelen.be/share/Example.zip), running on JBoss 7.1.1 with JSF Mojarra 2.2.0m12 and JDK 1.7

Comment: Sébastien Vanmechelen, I've imported the project with Netbeans 7.4 and executed with Glassfish 4 just fine! Oh, man! I was looking for this solution about 4 months ago and you solved that! I am really, really grateful and happy with it! Thank you so much and God bless you!

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the sample project is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can define AJAX calls on PF datatable filtering and/or paging.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBackingBean.values}" var="row" filteredValue="#{myBackingBean.filteredValues}" >
   <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{myBackingBean.updateSum}" update="componentToUpdate" />
   ...
</p:dataTable>
```

In your **updateSum()** method, you can walk through the **filteredValues** collection to do your business.

You may have some difficulties to target the update component enclosed in the datatable but this can be resolved by adding something like **styleClass="footerToUpdate"** to your  and using it in the  update with **update="@(.footerToUpdate)"**

Comment: This sounds nice, but how do I get the "filteredValues collection" ? And about the other events, sort and paginate ? Thanks.

Comment: The filteredValues collection is automatically populated. You only have to add this collection with a get/set in your backing bean and define the property in the datatable's code in the facelet like in my previous snippet.
For the 'sort' event, it is the same as the 'filter' event, you just have to change the 'event' attribute from 'filter' to 'sort'.

Comment: For the pagination, there is a 'page' event and you can store the current page information with a listener like :

public void onPage(PageEvent e) {
DataTable table = (DataTable) e.getComponent();
logger.info("Current Page : " + e.getPage() + " / Page Size : " + table.getRows());
}

You just have to play with all these event to update your sum in your backing bean and render it.

Another solution is to working with a lazy dataTable which retrieve only one page and compute your sum on the retrieved elements (cfr http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf).

Comment: Sébastien Vanmechelen, when 'jsf' shows the dataTable for the 1st time, it loads all the data from the db table. I deduce that the object (dataTable) stay in memory (client side JVM), right? As I'm working with a small dataSet, I can use this way we're discussing; otherwise, I should use the LazyLoad fashioned way, correct? I did what you said (please, see my updated code above), but the 'filtered list' is not being automatically populated. Did I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't have an Applet in your web page, there is no interaction between the browser page and the client JVM. The dataTable component stay in memory but on server side. Using this way may be fine. At first glance, your code seems to be Ok. I'll try to give you a full working example this afternoon.

Comment: Ok. I'll really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Sébastien Vanmechelen, I did not finished this yet. I found a very useful link, but didn't realized how to reproduce the example. Please, take a look and see if you can help me: http://chawi3.com/2012/11/09/primefaces-datatable-footer-total-with-filter-hack-version/